# Anomalies in QFT books

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, regularization, quantum-anomalies, chirality

Why in most QFT books when author discusses of non-invariance of measure of path integral (massless fermions interact with gauge fields)
$$
\int D\bar{\Psi} D\Psi \to |\Psi \to U\Psi , \quad \bar{\Psi} \to \bar{\Psi} \bar{U},\quad U = e^{i \alpha (x) \gamma_{5}t}, \quad  t^{\dagger} =t| \to \int D\bar{\Psi} D\Psi \det \left( U \right)^{-2}
$$
and looks only on infinitesimal transformations $U \approx 1 + i\alpha(x)\gamma_{5}t$ he doesn't introduce something like fictive particles (fictive, but formally independent) called ghosts in non-abelian gauge theories? Instead of this he introduces something like monster (like in Weinberg's "QFT" Vol. 2)
$$
\int D\bar{\Psi} D\Psi \to \int D\bar{\Psi} D\Psi e^{-2i\int d^{4}xTr
\left[\gamma_{5}tf \left( \frac{(\gamma_{\mu}D^{\mu}_{x})^{2}}{M^{2}}\right)\delta (x - y)\right]_{y \to x}},
$$
which is equal to summation over eigenstates of $\gamma_{\mu}D^{\mu}$ operator without introducing the new fields.

I don't understand this.

Comment: Could you be more specific *what* you don't understand? Why do you think that the ghosts should be discussed here? It is the fermion measure that turns out to be non-invariant, not the ghost measure. Also, why should we need them for the eigenstates of the Dirac operator?